# Code difference between PHP 5.3.10 and PHP 5.3.29

Tags: php, http, php-5.3

I need to make an HTTP call from a PHP script. I've tested it on my personal domain (running PHP 5.3.29) and it's all ok. When I've moved it on my customer domain (running PHP 5.3.10) the script starts having some problem.

In particular, this is the code that generate the error:

```
function BuildPlayFabHttpHeaders($i_PlayFabSecretKey) {

    $headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "X-SecretKey: $i_PlayFabSecretKey"
    ];

    return $headers;
}
```

I think the problem is with that kind of declaration, but I'm not a php expert. Can anyone help me to get this running on PHP 5.3.10?

Comment: "that generate the error" — What error?!

Comment: Try declaring your `$headers` variable with `array()` instead of `[]`

Comment: The most important thing here is to get your php versions updated to one that's still being supported. 5.6 minimum.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @commanderZiltoid it's important to realize that different companies support different versions, so it's best not to blindly recommend minimum versions.  I.E. Redhat still supports PHP 5.3 on RHEL6 and PHP 5.4 on RHEL7.

Comment: Thank you all for help. I solved the problem replacing [..] with array().

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't have worked on PHP 5.3.29 since the short array syntax `[..]` was introduced in PHP 5.4.

For anything under 5.4, you must use:

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

My assumption is your tests weren't actually using the PHP 5.3.29 binary but some other version installed on the system.

Comment: Thanks Devon, you were right. I have changed syntax and it works!
Only one thing, on my domain dashboard (I've bought it on Aruba) I see PHP version: 5.3.29. So I believe that 5.3.29 supports [..] syntax.

Anyway, thank you again.